# selected input with Ajax and PHP, how to call ajax on page load?

Tags: php, ajax, selected

I've been getting to grips with the basics of AJAX and PHP using this code [W3Schools - PHP & AJAX Database](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp). Would it be possible to add selected="selected" to one of the options and then have the ajax call to the PHP file as the page loads, rather than onchange? But obviously I'd still like the other options to load when selected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can use the body's `onLoad` event to trigger whatever you want. Completely valid next to an `onChange` event on the `<select>`.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't work out how to do it from just using onload in HTML but your suggestion made me think of using jQuery and document ready. This worked for me:

`$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
  });
$("#txtHint").load("getuser.php?uni=ntu");
});`

Comment: You didn't mention jQuery (in fact, if you had, I hadn't replied, because I do not know jQuery well enough), but nice to hear it got your problem fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Is possible that you only have to put SELECTED in the selection you want. For example:

```
<option value="1" selected>Peter Griffin</option>
```

The propierty `onChange` i thing will start listening the chages after load all the page.

regards